# GLFW multiple windows multiple threads OpenGL and Vulkan mix

Tags: glfw, vulkan, imgui

Qustion about GLFW
I have a program that has windows in OpenGL and one window with Vulkan.
When creating the Vulkan window I set

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
```

when I create OpenGL

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
```

My problem is after I create the Vulkan window I cannot create any other new windows.  If I call glfwCreateWindow it does not work.

> Glfw Error 65546: The specified window has no context

(I found this as a problem when working with ImGUI and multiple Viewports. that creates new window when dragging out of main window)

The creation on windows are on different threads.
How come one effects the others, and how to restore functionality to get the OpenGL Context back. so I can create more windows?
I am missing something here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating the OpenGL window, you must set the client API to OpenGL again via:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_API);
```

so that GLFW also creates an OpenGL context (and not *only* the window).
The *default* of this setting is `GLFW_OPENGL_API`, but when you explicitly *disable* OpenGL context creation for Vulkan via `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);` you must reenable OpenGL context creation back for the OpenGL window.

See: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_CLIENT_API_hint

Comment: Thanks this was the solution.